# GetMap request return white image

Tags: wms, mapserver

I just get a problem trying to display my map with GetMap request using Mapserver but it return a white image. I did search but i didn't found an answer :
My map file :

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT        -21 20 1 36  
  SIZE           700 400
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
      PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END
    OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME png
    MIMETYPE image/png
    DRIVER GD/PNG
    EXTENSION png
    IMAGEMODE PC256
    TRANSPARENT FALSE
  END
  WEB
  METADATA
    "wms_title" "Dans Layers and Stuff"
    "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?"
    "wms_enable_request" "*"
    "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
    "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
    "wms_format" "image/png"
  END
END
LAYER

NAME map1
TYPE polygon
STATUS default
CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
CONNECTION "dbname=postgres host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres"
DATA "geom from comgeo"
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END
  METADATA
    "wms_title" "map1"
  END
PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
CLASS
   STYLE
    COLOR 232 232 232
    OUTLINECOLOR 32 32 32
END
END
END
END
```

And this the Link i used for my request :

```
http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/wamp64/www/wordpress/map1.map&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-21,20,1,36&width=760&height=360&layers=map1&styles=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

The BBox values are correct. Thank you 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the probleme when i replace epsg:4326 with CRS:84 and the URL :

```
http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/wamp64/www/wordpress/map1.map&request=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&version=1.3.0&CRS=CRS:84&bbox=-21,20,1,36&width=700&height=400&layers=map1&styles=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

Comment: or you could switch the coordinate order in the BBOX

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing SERVICE=WMS parameter on your URL.

Comment: i tried this but i got thesame result : http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/wamp64/www/wordpress/map1.map&request=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&version=1.3.0&CRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-21,20,1,36&width=700&height=400&layers=map1&styles=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

Comment: In the database what does this query report"select st_extents(geom) from comgeo

Comment: select st_extent(geom) from comgeo return this : Box(-17.... 20..... -1..... 35..... )

Comment: Try adding to MAP CONFIG MS_ERRORFILE "/error.txt" and to LAYER DEBUG 5 then reload the map and look int /error.txt and it will display the SQL, you can then type the SQL into pgadmin3 and see if you get any results. You might also change STATUS DEFAULT to STATUS ON in the LAYER.

Answer (score 0):

Version of WMS 1.1.1 and WMS 1.3.0 have different request parameter for coordinate system : SRS=EPSG:4326 for 1.1.1 and CRS=CRS:84 for 1.3.0

see [mapserver wms](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html)

Comment: CRS=EPSG:4326 works on WMS 1.3.0 and gives coordinates in lat/long order which is as specified by EPSG for code 4326.  SRS=EPSG:4326 gives coordinates in long/lat order (which is incorrect ~ and reason why it was fixed in the WMS 1.3.0 specification).  CRS:84 exists for those that want to specify WGS:84 coordinates in long/lat order.